# How create JAVA SWING GroupBox similar in C#

Tags: java, swing, groupbox

I'm beginner JAVA. I'm using Swing tool for design GUI. 
I'm looking for GroupBox container similiar in C# winform. Any Help...

Thanks Guys.

**Update**

```
JPanel box = new JPanel();  
box.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[323.00][][27.00][197.00][][][56.00][]", "[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]"));
box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("192.168.10.101"));
add(box, "flowx,cell 3 0 1 4");

JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Start Offset X,Y:");
box.add(lblNewLabel, "flowx,cell 3 0");
```

Comment: Got a screen shot (of `GroupBox`)?  What are it's properties?

Comment: A picture of the desired look of the element would help. You might also want to include some code that you already have...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `JPanel` with a titled Border from the `BorderFactory`.

```
JPanel box = new JPanel();
box.add(new JLabel("Some element"));

box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Box Title"));
```

You can add any other components to the `JPanel` and lay them out as you wish. The Border just frames them... Here is a more extensive [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) which also explains different styles.